# How do I calculate the normals of a mesh in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am attempting and failing to calculate the normals of a triangle mesh using Haskell.

Given a list of vertices, each three consecutive vertices create a triangle:

```
[a, b, c,    d, e, f,     g, h, i ...]
```

A vertex is the following:

```
type Vertex = (Double, Double, Double, Double)
```

and a normal is:

```
type Normal = (Double, Double, Double)
```

And my function is:

```
calculateNormals :: [Vertex] -> [Normal]
calculateNormals v = map normalize normals
    where normals = concat $ zipWith3
        (\ a b c -> let normal = cross (c - a) (b - a)
                    in [normal, normal, normal])
        (every 3 v) (every 3 $ drop 1 v) (every 3 $ drop 2 v)
           every n xs = case drop (n - 1) xs of
               (y:ys) -> y : every n ys
               [] -> [[]
```

The gist of the function is that, for every 3 vertices, I calculate the cross product of the two vectors defining the triangle, and that is the normal. That's my intention - but I'm not sure if that's working...

Is there something obviously wrong with this method? Or is it how I implement it in Haskell?

Comment: I would write a function `verticesToTriangles :: [Vertex] -> [Triangle]` with `type Triangle = (Vertex, Vertex, Vertex)`, and implement it as `verticesToTriangles (a:b:c:rest) = (a, b, c) : verticesToTriangles rest`; `verticesToTriangles _ = []`.  Then you can get rid of your `every` function which isn't useful being generalized for any `n` since it's a local function.

Comment: @bheklilr That's a good point and I will do that. I don't think it's a root of the problem, but it does make it look cleaner.

Comment: You'll have to change your lambda function slightly as well, instead of `(\a b c ->` you'll need `(\(a, b, c) ->`, and instead of `concat $ zipWith3` you'll need `concatMap`, which is a lot cleaner.  Again, these are just suggestions to get your code cleaner, which often helps when searching for implementation problems.

Comment: Have you tried testing the output? Are you getting specific results that you think are wrong?

Comment: @Isaac I've been testing it visually and the results don't appear correct (or even close).

Comment: Are you sure that the inputs are correct? Can you provide some test data?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I'm testing with a cuboid and the vertices are hand entered and they are drawn correctly.

Comment: Sorry i'm not well versed in 3d programming, but why is `Vertex` a 4-tuple?

Comment: @Thomas Just because it's sometimes easier to represent points an infinite distance away when the fourth value is 0.0. Otherwise, it's almost always 1.

Comment: Can you please fill in the rest of the code needed to compile your code snippet?